# Is there any way to import classes to the jsp page (jsp+eclipse+java)

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin, editor

Is there any shortcut in Eclipse to import java class automatically into into jsp <%@ page import=""> tag
like as Ctrl+shift+o for java class in Eclipse

Comment: This is [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878433/how-to-import-classes-in-jsp-editor-eclipse)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ctrl+shift+o** does not work in eclipse for jsp file although you can just try writing

**<%@page import="com**

and then **crtl+space** it should provide you all the classes and package available.

One more thing...

Try this:

Type **YourClassName** anywhere on your JSP which you want to import and just hit **crtl+space** it will automatically add following line **<%@page import="package.YourClassName"%>**

Comment: ok... it mean we need to remember the exact package name of the class we are using.. right??